# Kiln 0.4.0 Problem VB (NixOS)

Tags: baking, kiln

I try to run Kiln 0.4.0 on a VirtualBox NixOS (Host Windows 10).

NixOS (VirtualBox appliances) https://nixos.org/nixos/download.html

After executing:

`ln -sf $(nix-build tezos-bake-central -A exe --no-out-link)/* app/`

Everything runs through (about 10-15 minutes)
And then i am getting the following error:

`error: build of '/nix/store/x5b7bcd0vngbn1z5dhpmb6kcndac8wf1-cabal2nix-obelisk-generated-static.drv' failed`

I've tried to execute (after CDed into "app"):
`./backend --network mainnet`

but I then got the error:
`-bash: ./backend: No such file or directory`

[Complete Error Log]
https://github.com/Blindripper/Docs/blob/master/kiln%200.4.0.%20NixOs%20Error.txt

Commit Hash:
fa8be8dea50689697bbf456109a15e74e7f5981f

Comment: Sorry to ask, should the `backing` tag be actually `baking`? It contains only one question.

Comment: "No such file or directory" is clear because the build failed and therefore the binary cannot be there.

Comment: Did you setup the nix cache?
https://gitlab.com/obsidian.systems/tezos-baking-platform/blob/develop/README.md

Comment: Can you please provide more of the logs from before and after `error: build of '/nix/store/x5b7bcd0vngbn1z5dhpmb6kcndac8wf1-cabal2nix-obelisk-generated-static.drv' failed`?

Comment: The most common cause of failed builds I've seen is due to running out of memory. Part of the static build step requires a really large amount of memory.

Comment: Added the complete error log. thx

Comment: @ElliotCameron i had indeed a memory problem before. I could solve it with "echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory". So i don't think that the actual problem has to do with the memory.

Comment: @Blindripper You're right. This is not a memory issue. Can you include the hash of the commit you're trying to build?

Comment: I misread your logs actually as Tom points out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This line of your log](https://github.com/Blindripper/Docs/blob/master/kiln%200.4.0.%20NixOs%20Error.txt#L138) suggests that your VM is out of memory. Could you try raising the allocated memory for your guest and see if that fixes it?

Comment: For posterity, the line is `ghc: internal error: Unable to commit 1048576 bytes of memory`

Comment: Thx will try it this evening and will give feedback. I thought "echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory" would vanish all Mem problems but i will try to raise the general memory of the machine.

Comment: Thx guys it works now :-) It was the memory. Raised it to 4GB (from 2GB).